# Применить метод Split к строке и вернуть массив, который сожержит разделители как отдельные элементы

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Можно ли каким-то образом разделить строку "**#hello This is an #example of some text with #hashtags and this #hashtags**" методом Split на части и получить такой результат:

```
res = ['#hello',' This is an ','#example', ' of some text with ', '#hashtags', ' and this ', '#hashtags']
```

Делить пытаюсь по словам, перед которыми есть "#", используя это регулярное выражение:

```
regex = /(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)/gm
```

Comment: А в чём именно вы выполняте JavaScript? Судя по описанию в https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Description , заключённые в скобки части регулярного выражения уже должны включаться в результат. В вашем случае остаётся только отфильтровать пустые строки.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt спасибо за ответ! До того, как задать вопрос, выводил в консоль результаты разделения и там были пустые строки и нужные мне разделители, правда затупил с фильтром, а сейчас осенило, все работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось проще простого, главное быть повнимательнее. Использование регулярного выражения в скобках в методе Split возвращает массив, который имеет все нужные значения и лишние пустые строки. Поэтому так можно решить эту задачу:

```js
let str = "#hello This is an #example of some text with #hashtags and this #hashtags";

let arr = str.split(/(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)/gm).filter(el => el);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Ого, не знал про фишку со скобками. Не стесняйтесь поставить галочку на свой ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `.match(regex)`

```js
let str = "#hello This is an #example of some text with #hashtags and this #hashtags moo";

let regex = /(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)|(.+?(?=(#|$)))/gm;

console.log( str.match(regex) );
```

Находит слова, начинающиеся на `#`, или `|` любой символ `.` один или много раз `+` до тех пор, пока не попадется новая решетка или конец строки `(?=(#|$))` — называется 'positive lookahead'.

Касаемо более универсального варианта... Кажется без переборов не обойтись:

```js
let str = "#hello This is an #example of some text with #hashtags and this #hashtags moo";

let arr = splitInclude(str, /#[A-Za-z0-9]+/gm);

console.log( arr );

/***/

function splitInclude(str, regex) {
  var match = str.match(regex);
  if( match === null ) return [str];
  
  var result = [];
  var lastIndex = 0;

  for( var i = 0; i < match.length; i++ ) {
    var index = str.indexOf( match[i], lastIndex );
    
    result.push( str.slice(lastIndex, index) );
    result.push( match[i] );
    
    lastIndex = match[i].length + index;
  }
  
  if( str.length > lastIndex ) result.push( str.slice(lastIndex) );
  
  if( ! result[0] ) result.shift();
  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!